# SHA256 encryption on a parameter in Postman

Tags: api, encryption, postman, sha256, postman-pre-request-script

We have 3 parameters that we need to send through the API.
One of them is the "apikey" which is a code already provided, the other one is "utcTimeStamp" and the last one is the "signature".

The signature consists of the result of encrypting with a SHA256 algorithm the following parameters:

apikey,privatekey,utcTimeStamp

(privatekey is a code that was also provided to us previously).

Including the comma between each parameter.

How could we generate this signature with these characteristics and return it as a parameter?

More details in the attached image.

[Image Desc. Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtlLz.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The documentation/developers of the API you are using should be able to let you know how to generate the signature. For example the Slack API uses this for verification of signatures: https://api.slack.com/authentication/verifying-requests-from-slack

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
let signature = CryptoJS.SHA256("some string").toString();
pm.environment.set("signature", signature);
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, then I should copy and paste this code in Pre-Request Script?

And it would look more or less like this?

let signature = CryptoJS.SHA256("apiKey,utcTimesatamp,other code here").toString();
pm.environment.set("signature", signature);

Comment: you could covert `apikey,privatekey,utcTimeStamp` to string first, then pass it to `"some string"`. Please double check how to structure signature with developers.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how would I do that?